# VBA code to auto serial number in column A after my userform entered data in column B

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a userform in which user can insert data and data will insert in column B to M. I need a code, either in worksheet or in userform to auto fill serial number starting with "RD 00001" which will fill in column A everytime data has enter. Please someone give me an idea.

Comment: See [When to use a Static variable](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/16978/when-to-use-a-static-variable#t=201609070306389229598).

Comment: _"I need a code..."_ is not the way this site works. Show your own efforts and ask about a specific problem. See [ask]

Comment: Sorry for the wrong word i used.Should I put my userform code to show my effort?? I just dont know how to start a serial number part.Newbie here.Not familiar with coding

Comment: So you want some sort of counter that increments ever time data is entered by the user?

Comment: Jim Hewitt,is that possible?? You suggest counter in userform code or in worksheet code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code behind this is very simple and designed for you to start on a blank sheet with `Row 1` being your header row. It's dynamic so essentially plug and play. Just call on the sub with whatever code you have for entering in the other data.

```
Sub SerialCode()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastSerial, digits, i As Integer
    Dim nextRow, lastRow As Long
    Dim newSerial As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    nextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last row in A
    lastRow = nextRow - 1
    newSerial = "" 'set value of our string blank

    If (nextRow - 1) < 2 Then 'If statement to catch if there's only a header
        lastSerial = 0
    Else: lastSerial = CInt(Replace(ws.Range("A" & lastRow).Value, "RD ", ""))
    End If

    lastSerial = lastSerial + 1
    digits = 6 - Len(lastSerial) 'how many 0's are there

    For i = 1 To digits
        newSerial = newSerial & "0" 'start building the string with 0's
    Next i

    newSerial = "RD " & newSerial & lastSerial 'concatenate the serial code
    ws.Range("A" & nextRow).Value = newSerial
End Sub
```

**NOTE:** whatever you have for finding your last row to input the other data, make sure your last row and this sub's last row are the same.

Comment: Ive been working with the code that will appear automaticly after user click submit form button.but i fail to upload my code here .

Comment: If you put my code in a module (lets call it module1), then in your button_click() sub at the end insert `Call Module1.SerialCode`. Or you can put this code in your UserForm code, and just `Call SerialCode`. Either way achieves the same thing.

Comment: I've got error :type mismatch in 'Else:lastSerial=CInt(Replace(ws.Range("A" & lastRow). Value, "RD",""))' when second data entered

Comment: Because you have something other than "RD 000000" in your serial

Comment: It should be. Second entered data should  be RD000002.

Comment: no, second entered data should be RD 000002, with the space, just like how you have it structured in your question.

Comment: If your serial code has a different format just alter my code to fit your needs. I do think this has answered the question, could you mark it as answered?